# extract end of the string

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following string:

```
 Hey this is a test
```

I'm trying to extract it using the following regex:

```
 string buffer = "Hey this is a test";
 Regex r = new Regex("Hey this is a (.*?)", RegexOptions.Multiline);
 Match m = r.Match(buffer);
```

But for some reason I cannot extract it. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: What sort of output are you expecting?

Comment: m.groups[1].value = test

Comment: If you want to extract it using `m.Value`, you need to use regex with positive lookbehind: `(?<=Hey this is a ).*`. If you need only last word, you can use `\S*$` regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `.*?` tries to take minimum amount of chars. In your case zero.
2. `()` is a group. So the result be in `m.Groups[1]`

   ```
   string buffer = "Hey this is a test";
   Regex r = new Regex("Hey this is a (.*)", RegexOptions.Multiline);
   Match m = r.Match(buffer);
   Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]); // test
   ```
3. It is better to use more simple code. For example to take last word from string you can split the string by  `' '` and take the last element:

   ```
   string buffer = "Hey this is a test";
   Console.WriteLine(buffer.Split(' ').Last());
   ```